# How to put data from userform to specified cells

Tags: vba, userform

I want to transfer data from my userform to specified excel cells. But there seems to be some problems as I can't get it to work. This is my code below. Any help would be so much appreciated

```
Private Sub Confirm1_Click()

Dim Voorspellen As Worksheet
Set Voorspellen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Poisson")

Voorspellen.Range("B5") = CDate(DatumLijn1_txt.Text)
Voorspellen.Range("C5") = TimeValue(UurLijn1_txt.Text)
Voorspellen.Range("F5") = PredictorIngeven.cmoThuisLijn1
Voorspellen.Range("G5") = PredictorIngeven.cmoAwayLijn1
Voorspellen.Range("G5") = Val(PredictorIngeven.HomeOddsLijn1_txt.Text)
Voorspellen.Range("H5") = Val(PredictorIngeven.AwayOddsLijn1_txt.Text)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I have no errors but my data isn't in the cells I specified...

Comment: Voorspellen.Range("B5") .value, does this help?

Comment: nope still the same.

My userform is in the "Voorspellen"sheet and the data has to be in the "Poisson" sheet. So I assume Dim Voorspellen As Worksheet
Set Voorspellen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Poisson") is correct?

Comment: Are there other text in the Poisson sheet?

Comment: Voorspellen only contains my userform. Poisson contains / or should contain all the data that I've entered in my userform. But my poisson sheet stays empty...

Comment: Have you tried to enter data manually at these cells?

Comment: of course. And works without any problems

Comment: what is PredictorIngeven?

Comment: the name of my userform

Comment: Can you post picture of your userform?

Comment: posted a pic in teh desciption of my problem. So that userform is in sheet "Voorspellen".

Datum should go to B5 in the Poisson sheet
Uur should go to C5 ...
Thuis should go to D5
Uit should go to E5
Home Odds should go to F5
Away odds should go to G5

Comment: Have you tried putting the `me.` in front of all the textbox calls, like this `CDate(Me.DatumLijn1_txt.Text)

Comment: is the button on the form or sheet?

Comment: button is on the userform

Comment: try using a msgbox to show you the values instead, see what comes out.

Comment: `Me.` references the parent from which the sub is called, in this case your userform.

Comment: nothing worked so far. Tried all your solutions... but nothing